# I updated ubuntu to 14.04 and nautilus disappeared

Tags: 14.04

I'm sorry im all new to this. I don't know how to activate nautilus.. The sidebar with my desktop icons disappeared also. I can't do anything. Please help..

Comment: try to do ctrl+alt+F1 (to open tty session)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something went wrong with your window manager.

Try opening a console (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and typing `nautilus`.

This should open up nautilus to your `/home/user` folder. If this works, but your sidebar is still missing, you may wish to try

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

This will likely take a while (as it re downloads and reconfigures a bunch of files) but should, hopefully, solve your issues.

Comment: When i type ctrl+alt+t nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

(ctrl+alt+F1) and you will switch out of your X session. Log in with your username and password and type `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` And see what happens.

Comment: It says unable to locate package ubuntu-desktop.